# Get urls from a string as an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to get any urls from a string as an array
I do use a node module for that

```js
const getUrls = require("get-urls")
url = getUrls(message.content)
```

but it doesn't get urls like "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/692008084779958383/706079694843281438/1533640875_b6922c68f37d1add2bfce46a59978531.jpg"

Is there any other way to get the urls from a message as an array which can also detect an url like the one above thanks

Comment: how does `getUrls` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

`get-urls` returns urls in normalized form (as a js Set).
You can easily convert it to an array:

```
const getUrls = require("get-urls");
urls = getUrls(message.content);
Array.from(urls);
```